# In Ahsoka what type of the communication hologram was that?

Tags: star-wars, props

I just saw Ahsoka S1E2 and was wondering what kind of holographic communication was being used in the end?

It was very different to the normal, mechanical versions of holograms often seen in Star Wars. This one was more fluid and interesting...

> The call happened between Morgan Elsbeth on her ship to Baylan Skoll, Shin Hati and Marrok.
>
>  [image: the communication]
>
>  My guess would be it was some technology on top of the mechanical holocomm based on some Nightsister magicks, but was it?

Comment: *"My guess would be it was some technology on top of the mechanical holocomm based on some Nightsister magicks"* - Yup

Comment: Ya, it *seems like we may be in for new kinds of tech and/or metaphysics, considering the other reveal.